# How to limit quantity of windows opened when user clicks [view record] in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I limit the amount of windows opened from a grid-view in an web (web forms) application?

I have a grid-view that has a view link for each row. Each time I click on Edit I can open a new window to present details about the record, but I want to force the application to close the previous window opened before showing the next one.

I've tried to implement Singleton, but it didn't work (that window needs to update x seconds). I also attempted using [Application.OpenForms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-list-of-all-open-forms-in-windows-application1), but that's only for WPF.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Why does the form needing to update every X seconds matter if it is a singleton or not?

Comment: Static count on a class, that increments on launch, and decrements on close?